# I used Multisim to simulate a circuit with an LM358 but it doesn't work. What is the problem?

Tags: circuit-analysis, multisim

[image: circuit image]

The input is 1V.  The output should be 1V*(1+R2/R1)=2V but the output in Multisim is 742.09mV.  What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simulated chip needs power supplies connected to pins 4 and 8. If you use +/-15V the circuit should work (+15 on pin 8 and -15 on pin 4). Lower voltages such as 0V on pin 4 and 15V on pin 8 should also work in this particular instance.

A real chip would probably not behave in exactly this way with no supplies, but there's no real incentive to model pathological situations like "power supply pins left open".

By the way, your calculation of the expected output voltage is also incorrect.

Comment: your answer works.I thought that the chip is on power default in multisim,thanks a lot.

Comment: In general if the pins are there you probably have to connect to them. There may be other models (eg. ideal op-amp) with some default power supply.

Answer (score 1):

> what is wrong?

Because you didn't give any supply voltage to the op amp (see the vertical pins floating).

Check the datasheet, see the recommended supply voltage range, and apply to the op amp.